# Stylesheet Javascript wont load Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Alright I know it's a ridiculous question, but I really searched everywhere and I don't know what to do. On Firefox or IE my css nor the js files will properly load. Yes I deleted my cache and cookies and everything else, but nothing changes not sure why...

The website is: ic-marketing.com

Anyone has a clue what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: "We make your website work across all devices". Oh the irony.

Comment: Your bootstrap doesn't seem to load in Firefox somehow. When I go to http://ic-marketing.com/css/bootstrap.min123.css, it loads perfectly fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, I get a completely blank screen. In IE it prompts the download screen, but that one does end up opening the correct file though.

Comment: It looks like your server is rejecting to send information if the browser isn't Google Chrome. Weird...

Comment: What do you have as a backend ? It seems that the error isn't at the front-end layer.

Comment: @Joeytje50 ah c'mon man I'm working towards that goal. Yes working with bootstrap for now but setting up the basics. Didn't have time to cache bust those files but even that not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I checked the requests and I concluded that your server have something messed.

The requests to css files do not receive data in Firefox. But the headers looks ok.

Here is the response header form Firefox

```
Accept-Ranges:"bytes"
Connection:"keep-alive"
Content-Encoding:"x-deflate"
Content-Length:"99961"
Content-Type:"text/css"
Date:"Sun, 25 May 2014 02:23:29 GMT"
Last-Modified:"Sat, 24 May 2014 16:06:41 GMT"
Server:"nginx/1.6.0"
```

And there is the response header from Google Chrome

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:x-deflate
Content-Length:99961
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Sun, 25 May 2014 02:19:04 GMT
Last-Modified:Sat, 24 May 2014 16:06:41 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.0
```

They are the same. The only difference is that the Firefox come without a content.

So, I tested the requests via cUrl.

Here is the request headers based on the Google Chrome request.

```
curl 'http://ic-marketing.com/css/bootstrap.min123.css' 
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' 
-H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' 
-H 'Referer: http://ic-marketing.com/' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```

It does bring the css file...

But so, I made a Firefox like cUrl

```
curl 'http://ic-marketing.com/css/bootstrap.min123.css'
-H 'Host: ic-marketing.com'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0' 
-H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' 
-H 'Referer: http://ic-marketing.com/' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

And it brings to me a cPanel error says "404 - PAGE NOT FOUND".

That is because the Firefox request have this header

```
-H 'Host: ic-marketing.com'
```

This header make the request crash. But, why ?

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's very weird. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Is there -H 'Host: ic-marketing.com' header that is breaking the request. I suggest you to contact your server admin, or your hosting support.

Comment: Yup will contact them and ask about that Host in the header, will get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you  have A js error loading, the IE is not so strict as others

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min123.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just saw the error that "123" at the end.